# how to change the widget of view's exposed filter form?

Tags: views

I have an exposed filter form, and its default widgets are textfields. I'd like to change them to selects based on values from database.
I have tried `hook_form_alter` and `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter`, but get an error:

```
An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

The code I used to change the widget is like this and I've tried `#validate` option.

```
$form['field_address_province'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $province_options,
        '#validate' => true,
        '#description' => 'Select address',
    );
```

Edit:

Sorry for the lack of infomation.
The `$province_options` is an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Please Select
    [6] => Area1
    [7] => Area2
    [2] => Area3
)
```

Comment: what is the return value of $province_options array?

Comment: show the content inside the $province_options array.

Comment: The first key must be empty string. Did you try to add options like this?: Array
(
    '' => Please Select //EMPTY STRING
    6 => Area1
    7 => Area2
    2 => Area3
)

Comment: i tested this kind of thing and found that when you try to switch a exposed widget field you need to provide an array with the empty first key, if it is checkboxes or radios, if new widget will be a select than you need to provide an array with the 'All' first key

Comment: @xurshid29 Thank you, it works and the error disappeared. But '#default_value' option still doesn't work. Btw, is there any reference that show this "empty string" thing? This is the first time that I know empty string can be used as hash key in php...

Comment: @xurshid29, you should add your comment as answer.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Ok, I'll add this as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested this kind of thing and found that when you try to switch a exposed widget field you need to provide an array with the empty first key, if it is checkboxes or radios; if new widget will be a select then you need to provide an array with the 'All' first key. E.g.:

```
//Suppose that you have a default input widget which you want to change to select widget.
//We will get the values which we want our new select widget will get as options:
$opts = array(
  'first_key' => 'First value',
  'sec_key' => 'Second value',
);

// Then we will add required 'All' first key:
$options = array('All' => 'Choose a value') + $opts;

// Then we will create our new select widget
$form['YOUR_FIELD_NAME'] = array(
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#title' => t('MY TITLE'),
     '#options' => $options,
   );
```

Comment: It seems like 'All' still get the ERROR. I still have to use EMPTY STRING as key.

Comment: @leetom I don't know why it is happening, but in my case select widget gets "All" as first option value, e.g.: `<select id="edit-field-adv-mark-tid" class="form-select" name="field_adv_mark_tid" tabindex="-1">
<option class="" value="All">--Выберите</option>
<option class="" value="438">Marka 1</option>
<option class="" value="439">Marka 2</option>
<option class="" value="1190">Marka 6</option>
<option class="" value="1194">Marka 7</option>
</select>`

Comment: @leetom if I change that value then I get that ERROR, like "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

Comment: I wonder what's your views version. I am using views 3.7. I figured out that if I don't set the filter's value (first loading page), then the value is NULL, and NULL isn't in these options unless I add an option with EMPTY STRING as key (aka filter value). If I use 'All', '<Any>', or '-Any-' as the default option's key, I have to set filter's value to it in `hook_init`. I found [this link](https://drupal.org/node/1177882)